# Included category propagates to other included files?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, categories, propagation

So, basically here's what I want to do. I'm testing a class and in order to do that I want to redefine "today" (or "now"), meaning that I can test date transitions and other related properties simply by stating, say, "tomorrow is now" and then write my asserts.

My idea is to put a custom Test category on NSDate (NSDate+Test). But, at this moment I'm no longer sure how and where that category will propagate. I mean, will my class-under-test (that uses NSDate) automatically start to use NSDate+Test?

Just to illustrate:

```
#include "MyClassUnderTest.h"
#include "NSDate+Test.h"

// Will MyClassUnderTest.h see and use NSDate+Test at all times?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime will happily add the methods to `NSDate`, but the compiler will error out if you try to send a message that it hasn't seen declared.*

So as long as you import the header, your class will be able to use your new methods.

If you're talking about "overriding" a framework class's methods in a category, you should be aware that *every* use of that method in your process will use the new version. So if you clobber `+[NSDate date]`, even Cocoa-internal calls to `date` will use your version.** This can easily result in weird, even dangerous behavior. You should prefer mocking to this kind of clobbering.

Also note that, because of this phenomenon, you should *always* prefix methods that you add to framework classes via categories.

---

*Under ARC, at least.

**Assuming that `date` was not originally itself implemented in a category; in that case, the results are "undefined behavior".

Comment: Ok, big thanks! This was what I suspected, but without a clear understanding as to why. Now I do!